# Как подчищать тень блоков 3D куба?

Tags: javascript

```
var block = $(".cube");
var index_img = 1;
var cur = 1;
var next = cur + 1;
var img = $(".cube div");
var button = $(".button");
var deg = 90;
var images = new Array("http://www.avataris-faun.ru/avatars_200x200/436.jpg","http://images.stopgame.ru/uploads/avatars/avatar_303989.gif","http://stat18.privet.ru/ah/0a2120f74a5258b7e57c50238f9126e0","http://stat21.privet.ru/lr/0c13092ff81da25919bf841ece0eafd8","http://i2.guns.ru/forums/icons/forum_pictures/000743/743965.jpg");

img[cur-1].style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)";

$(button).click(function (){
index_img = $(this).index();

  for(h=0;h > 4;h++)
  {
   if (h!==(cur-1))
     {
      img[h].style.boxShadow = "none"; 
     }   
  }

  if ( cur > 3)
    {
      cur = 0;
    }
img[cur].style.background = "url(" + images[index_img] + ")"; 
  block[0].style.transform = "rotate3d(1,0,0," + deg + "deg)";

  img[cur-1].style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 200px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";

  deg = deg + 90;

   cur++;  
});
```

Имеется 3D куб. Слайдер изображений. Он постоянно крутится по x на 90 градусов. К каждому повороту меняется следующая картинка на выбранную. Также я добавил бокс шадоу. 4 раза работает нормально, но потом зависает. Каким образом можно подчищать у других блоков тень? Пытался сделать цикл, чтобы во всех блоках, кроме текущего, тень стояла "none". Не работает. Итог. Создаем тень для двух блоков, которые попадают в область видимости, и чистим тень у двух других.